# Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found. giving me this erroe when try to run my code

Tags: android, visual-studio, gradle

```
I have create a project in the visual studio code when i run the project its giving me the following errors i do not understand why it is giving me this error please some on help me
```

> Error which is showing

Launching lib\main.dart on SM J200F in debug mode...
?/SENTINEL_TAG(20518): SENTINEL_MSG_LIBCUTILS
?/SENTINEL_TAG(20518): SENTINEL_MSG_LIBLOG
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Farman Ullah\Desktop\FlutterProjects\flutter_blog_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25
  Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.

**

> 1. build.gradle code

```
{


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

}
```